# Where is `git add` in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, `Cmd-Shift-P` gives me the command palette. There are many Git commands listed in the palette, but the only result for "add" is "Add file to .gitignore". This is not what I want. I want the equivalent of `git add $CURRENT_FILE`. Such a command is provided, for example, by [the git-plus extension to Atom](https://atom.io/packages/git-plus). What is its equivalent in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I eventually found it: the command is called `Git: Stage Changes`. Visual Studio confusingly deviates from Git terminology here. There is [a (sadly closed) GitHub issue regarding this problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47876).

Comment: Yeah it is annoying that vs code doesn’t use “add”, but “stage changes” is _technically_ correct. Not sure why thy don’t use the more common term though.

Comment: Also annoying that there isn’t a prominent GUI way to do this.

Comment: Your issue on github is now open again. I hope people will vote for it. We need 20 thumbs up!

Comment: Found that it's apparently not the same. If you resolve conflicts e.g. after rebase, when you use "Git: Stage Changes" in VSCode, nothing happens. If you run `git add <file>` on command line, it's added to the index. So: there is a difference.

Comment: I think the current VS Code terminology is simply incorrect. Please, vote bug https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/167715 in case you want to see a change here.

Answer (score 2):

With **Stage Change** command you can add your file in git repo.

[image]

In the left-top side of image there is **+ (plus)** icon you just have to click and your file will be add in local git repo.

Comment: To see the _Stage Shange (+)_ button, first, select the source control view (little graph icon) on the left bar. This is highlighted in the screenshot above.